# Linux how to write a python file without an IDE

Tags: linux

4. Make a copy of a computer python file you wrote for some other course without an IDE just a simple text editor
5. Modify this program slightly, without using an IDE.
6. Run the modified program, without using an IDE

How do I create a python file with linux?

Comment: What is 4,5 and 6. Where are steps 1,2 and 3 ? not the downvoter though, :-)

Comment: 4.5. "Google `linux text editor`."

Comment: Try nano, it's a basic text editor.

Comment: The harder question is how to write one with an IDE... If you are going to be using Linux for anything, bite the bullet, spend 30 minutes on a `vim` tutorial and you will be able to edit files on practically any system you sit down to. Once you wrap your head around the fact there are 2 basic modes in vim (1) command mode - default, you can't type here, you manipulate text/files, and (2) insert mode (type `i`) and you can type now, and hit `ESC` to return to command mode, you're good to go. [Vim Tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Tutorial) (and grab a cheat sheet for commands)

Answer (score 3):

To create a python file using Linux use command `touch` to create a file(will create a file in current directory, to know the current directory use `cd` command)

```
touch myfile.py
```

Open the file using one of the available text editors, for example vi:

```
vi myfile.py
```

Type your code and use command `:wq` to save and close the file.

```
a=2
b=3
print a+b
```

Run your code using `python` command:

```
python myfile.py
5  #output
```

To check or install Python on Linux, please refer to AWS detailed instructions: [LINK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux-python.html)

To get more instructions on using vi editor: [LINK](http://staff.washington.edu/rells/R110/)

Answer (score 0):

It is as usual with writing c programs and others. No difference at all. If you are familiar with linux command line you can use command line  text editors. Otherwise  use gedit , sublime text,vs code,atom..etc (all are text editors with GUI) just as you use a notepad in windows.